# How use query result in current layer in Hive?

Tags: hive

for exmaple

```
select
    sum(a) over(partition by aa) as x,
    sum(b) over(partition by bb) as y,
    (x- y) / y as c -- look here
from 
    table
```

I want to use x,y as a variable here,
how avoid write as

```
 ((sum(a) over(partition by aa) as x) - (sum(b) over(partition by bb) as y)) / sum(b) over(partition by bb) as y
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not let you use aliases directly, you can use your query as an inner query or a derived table like below:

```
select  x,y,(x- y) / y as c from 
(select
sum(a) over(partition by aa) as x,
sum(b) over(partition by bb) as y,
from 
table1)
```

Alternately, if you have an identifier column say id, you can even use the WITH function of Hive:

```
with sub_table as (
select id, sum(a) over(partition by aa) as x,
        sum(b) over(partition by bb) as y
from table1)
select a.id,
b.x,
b.y,
(b.x- b.y) / b.y as c
from table1 a
join sub_table b
on(a.id = b.id);
```

Comment: but it would make code long and redundant while code is complicated

Comment: Unfortunately, that is a limitation of Hive currently. Using derived tables or macros or inner queries is the only way to use the aliases. Aliases of columns cannot be used within select query.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it was acceptable/helpful.

Comment: I’d love to do this but it is useless for me